# Online job application

Tags: web-applications

I am trying to add an application to my site where I can post job openings with my company and allow people to apply online.

Can someone recommend a service or app already in existence for this purpose?

I tried googling it, but could not find a set of search terms that did not return endless sites for job seekers.

This is a (very) small business and I do not expect to have more than a few openings at any time, but what I am actually interested in is having a repository of interested job seekers to have on file.  Then when people ask me about openings, I could just refer them to the page and they could apply.  Then, if we have an opening, we could look through the list of candidates and if we can't fill the position(s) from that list, we could post the job and advertise to fill the position.

Comment: How big is your organization and how many positions will be available at any given time?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution i could think of would be to set-up a google form and people to post answers to questions these then get posted back to google spreadsheets, its really basic and would not scale, but would allow you to start to collect data.

I would also try Googling for something like "open source job board" that should throw up a few examples you could set-up on a sub domain - take a look at [Jobberbase][1] as a good example.

Otherwise I would say you are looking to spend some money and then depending on what you are after its either a careers site or some sort of applicant tracking system (ATS) and these range in price and functionality (again possible search terms).

I work in the online recruitment sector so if the above is a little off target post an update and I will try to advise further.

As @Lese has said it really does depend on size and volume to the type of solution you need as you hinted you are quiet small with a low volume you should think simple to begin with.

[1]: http:// www.jobberbase.com